# VUEX, what to do when $store.state is null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

When users are not logged into my website, the state of `user` is set to `null`.
However, this throws up a lot of issues on some pages where i look to see if `this.$store.user`

For example, if I were to have a simple check such as

```
if (this.$store.getters.userInfo.likedProjects.includes(title)) {this.hasLiked = true}
```

and the user is not logged in (thus, setting the state of user to null by default) I get this error;

```
_this.$store.getters.userInfo is null
```

How should I correctly handle this sort of issues so that my console does not get flooded with typescript errors?

My initial idea was to first check `if user.loggedIn == true` and wrap everything inside of that, but that seems awfully messy just to avoid some errors...

Comment: use optional chaining ? https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-optional-chaining/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining), which is available in TypeScript 3.7+:

```
if (this.$store.getters.userInfo?.likedProjects.includes(title)) {
    this.hasLiked = true;
}
```

If `userInfo` is null or undefined, then the entire statement `this.$store.getters.userInfo?.likedProjects.includes(title)` will return `undefined` instead of throwing an error.

If `likedProjects` may also be null or undefined, then you need to use optional chaining on that property too, i.e.:

```
if (this.$store.getters.userInfo?.likedProjects?.includes(title)) {
    this.hasLiked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(this.$store.getters.userInfo){
    if (this.$store.getters.userInfo.likedProjects.includes(title)) {this.hasLiked = true}
}
```